# Center align spinner prompt text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have an android spinner

```
        <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/input_height"
                android:id="@+id/items"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:prompt="@string/item_prompt"/>
```

And a custom adapter attached to it. I manage to center text by passing my own layout in

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and

```
public View getDropDownView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
```

However it seems that I can't center prompt text. How would I go about doing that?

EDIT: This is the prompt text I want centered [image: This is the text I want centered]

Comment: can you add a screenshot

Comment: I managed to get the selected item centered but it seems that did not work for the prompt in drop down

Comment: *I can't center prompt text*. You mean the text from the spinner dropdown?

Comment: @J'' I added the screenshot

Comment: @Quillion, I guess you will have to do a custom implementation

Comment: @J'' that is what I would like to know how to do. I can't go about figuring out what to do there